# Problem with installing mediapipe using pip on windows

Tags: python, pip, mediapipe

So when i am trying pip install mediapipe i see error like that `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe`
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPuy5.png)
Here is image of error and pip and python version
I have 64-bit python

Comment: Actually I just try it and download successfully in my Windows PC. (Python 3.10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current latest version mediapipe 0.9.0.1 [provides wheels](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/0.9.0.1/#files) for Windows for Python 3.7-3.10. A wheel for Python 3.11 is only available for Linux.

The bottom line is: don't be so quick to upgrade your Python, wait until all 3rd-party libraries you use are caught up.

Downgrade your Python, use Python 3.10 64-bit. Or try to [build from sources](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/python#building-mediapipe-python-package).

Comment: After downgrading to 3.9.0 i still can't install mediapipe with same error

Comment: @Kubzel Python 3.9? 64-bit? `python --version`? `pip --version`?

Comment: Yea 64-bit C:\Users\kubzel>pip --version
pip 22.3.1 from c:\users\kubzel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

C:\Users\kubzel>py --version
Python 3.9.0

Comment: @Kubzel `python39-32` doesn't look like 64-bit. More like 32-bit Python installed on 64-bit Windows. What is the output of `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`

Comment: Ah sorry its my bad i will change to 64bit

Comment: Its working now thx everybody for help

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install mediapipe--user
```

And restart kernel

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your python interpreter my worked for 3.8.9 and use mediapipe  0.8.10.1
As mediapipe only support python 3.8 - 3.11